# how to validate the Azure CLI or az command before execute?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

Looking for a way to validate the AZ command result before the actual implementation.

Below is the command I want to test, The requirement is that, i need to validate the result before  applying the command. I know this is possible in ARM template deployment, but is it not allowed in AzureCLI ?

```
az monitor metrics alert condition create --aggregation {Average, Count, Maximum, Minimum, Total}
                                          --metric
                                          --op {Equals, GreaterOrLessThan, GreaterThan, GreaterThanOrEqual, LessThan, LessThanOrEqual, NotEquals}
                                          --type {dynamic, static}
                                          [--dimension]
                                          [--namespace]
                                          [--num-periods]
                                          [--num-violations]
                                          [--sensitivity {High, Low, Medium}]
                                          [--since]
                                          [--skip-metric-validation {false, true}]
                                          [--subscription]
                                          [--threshold]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, **`Whatif`** is only available for az group or subscription deployment and it cant be used in a single line or direct mode `az` commands.

- There is debug option in other `az` cmd but i don't think it will serve your purpose.

For more information please refer the below links:

- [ARM template deployment what-if operation| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell)
- [Az deployment|MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest)
- [Az CLI reference| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/service-page/list%20a%20-%20z?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: can we add azure cli command part as of the resourcemanager deployment ?

Comment: No @Vowneee, We can not add cli command in template deployment .